# Angular not evaluating expression in form action

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular view, I'm using an expression for a form action. Mysteriously, it's not being evaluated and is instead making an HTTP request for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{ apiUrl }}` instead of whatever apiUrl is set to.

apiUrl is being set by the following code: `$scope.apiUrl = config.APIURLBase + '/api/upload';`, which looks like it should be working fine.

Any ideas?

```
<h1>Upload new File</h1>
<form action="{{ apiUrl }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form" class="dropzone" ng-dropzone dropzone="dropzone" dropzone-config="dropzoneConfig">
    <div class="dz-message">
        Drop files here or click to upload
    </div>
    <div class="fallback">
        <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran across something similar and doing the following fixed it for me.

```
$scope.api = config.APIURLBase;
```

And in your form

```
<form action="{{ api + '/api/upload' }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form" class="dropzone" ng-dropzone dropzone="dropzone" dropzone-config="dropzoneConfig">
```

Comment: I tried that, same result. Will try it again today however.

Comment: Tried it, now is just requesting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{ apiUrl + '/api/upload' }}`

Comment: Of course, it was a PICNIC error. The controller wasn't set!